# Single character console input in java/clojure

Tags: java, clojure, user-input, console.readkey

How can I read a single character/key from the console without having to hit Enter?  There is an [old entry in Sun's bug database](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6351276) claiming that it can't be done in pure java.  I've found these approaches

- JNI
- JLine [http://jline.sourceforge.net/]
- Javacurses [http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses/]

I'd expect to add a single `magic-readkey.jar` to my classpath, and to write a few lines of code, like `(def just-hit (com.acme.MagicConsole/read-char))`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's an "immediate echo" app using JLine which will print `int`s corresponding to registered keypresses, structured as a [Leiningen](http://github.com/technomancy/leiningen) project:

1. `project.clj`:

   ```
   (defproject con "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
     :description "FIXME: write"
     :main con.core
     :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.1.0"]
                    [org.clojure/clojure-contrib "1.1.0"]
                    [jline "0.9.94"]])
   ```
2. `src/con/core.clj`:

   ```
   (ns con.core
     (:import jline.Terminal)
     (:gen-class))

   (defn -main [& args]
     (let [term (Terminal/getTerminal)]
       (while true
         (println (.readCharacter term System/in)))))
   ```

The functionality in question is provided by the `jline.Terminal` class, which provides a static method `getTerminal` returning an instance of a platform-specific subclass which can be used to interact with the terminal. See the [Javadoc](http://jline.sourceforge.net/apidocs/index.html) for more details.

Let's see what `asdf` looks like...

```
$ java -jar con-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar 
97
115
100
102
```

(<kbd>C-c</kbd> still kills the app, of course.)

Comment: If you try the code above, you will find that it does in fact work without enter/return. (Verified just now on an Ubuntu box with openjdk-8-jdk. It seems that clojure-contrib 1.1.0 is no longer available from Central, but you can simply remove it and things will still work – dependency versions are not up to date because this answer dates back to 2010.)

Comment: Not sure, but my Termina.readCharacter simply reads from System.in and still needs to wait for enter

Comment: If that's the behaviour you see with the above version of JLine etc., then my first guess would be that this is a problem with your terminal application, or else some other platform issue. You could see if, say, a simple C program echoing keys works fine – that would make a problem external to the JVM less likely. Might be worth experimenting with other approaches in that case – Lanterna seems very cool indeed (couldn't use it in 2010, as it was released in 2012).

Answer (score 4):

For anyone who may be reading this in 2015 and beyond, note that more recent versions of JLine no longer have the method `Terminal/getTerminal`. I'm sure there is another (possibly better) way to do this now with JLine2, but you can always just use `jline "0.9.94"` and the accepted answer will still work, at least up to Clojure 1.6 (of note, you no longer need to require `clojure.contrib`).

As an alternative, I would recommend the excellent [clojure-lanterna](http://sjl.bitbucket.org/clojure-lanterna), which is a Clojure wrapper around the Java [Lanterna](https://code.google.com/p/lanterna/) library. As you can see in [the docs](http://sjl.bitbucket.org/clojure-lanterna/terminals/#input), there are `get-key` and `get-key-blocking` functions for reading in single characters of input.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use jline2 there is a `ConsoleReader` class available which does pretty much the same thing Michał Marczyk explained above:

```
(ns con.core
  (:import jline.console.ConsoleReader)
  (:gen-class))


(defn -main [& args]
  (while true (->> (ConsoleReader.) (.readCharacter) (println))))
```