# Reading unbuffered keyboard input in Clojure

Tags: clojure

How does one read a single keystroke from the terminal (not Swing) in Clojure?

I have tried a few things including [various](http://jline.sourceforge.net/) [versions](https://github.com/jline/jline2) of the JLine library, but have not gotten it working (see example below).

I will happily accept a working, Unix-only (Mac, Linux, ...) example.  Ideally I'd like to know how to switch buffering off for both stdin and stdout.

Here's something close:

```
;; project.clj dependencies:
;; [[org.clojure/clojure "1.4.0"]
;;  [jline/jline "2.8"]])

(ns slosh.core
  (:import [jline.console ConsoleReader])
  (:gen-class))    

(defn -main []
  (println "start")
  (let [cr (ConsoleReader.)]
    (.readCharacter cr)
    (println "done")))
```

This prints "start" but does not respond to any input except control-C.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure how you are running this, but if you are using `lein run`, you will run into problems.  Try using `lein trampoline run`.

I would link [Single character console input in java/clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225025/single-character-console-input-in-java-clojure)  but I don't seem to have enough Internet Points to do that.

Comment: `lein trampoline run` does indeed work, as does running from the überjar.  Any ideas why one works and not the other?

Comment: The `sh` function used with `lein run` only hooks up `out` and `err` of the project run as a subprocess (see https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/leiningen-core/src/leiningen/core/eval.clj#L155). `trampoline` causes the project to be run as an independent process with its `in`, `out`, and `err` hooked up by the shell.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe also have a look at [clojure-lanterna](https://clojars.org/clojure-lanterna).

Comment: Also looks good - thanks for the link.  Will try that library if I get blocked using jline2.