# How to make a clojure program block until a key is pressed?

Tags: clojure

How can I make a clojure program block until a key is pressed?

I want the equivalent behaviour of a blocking read from stdin in other languages.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13435541/reading-unbuffered-keyboard-input-in-clojure

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use ConsoleReader from JLine.

See the Clojure Cookbook for details: https://github.com/clojure-cookbook/clojure-cookbook/blob/master/04_local-io/4-02_read-unbuffered-keystroke.asciidoc

The question in JohnJ's comment ([Reading unbuffered keyboard input in Clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13435541/reading-unbuffered-keyboard-input-in-clojure)) gives a very similar example to the one in the Cookbook.